# Yeoman yo webapp fails with TypeError

Tags: javascript, yeoman

After upgrading to nodejs 0.10.0 and npm 1.2.14 yeoman 1.0 beta fails if I try to create a webapp:

```
$ yo webapp

path.js:360
        throw new TypeError('Arguments to path.join must be strings');
              ^
TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings
    at path.js:360:15
    at Array.filter (native)
    at Object.exports.join (path.js:358:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node-v0.10.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/bower/lib/core/config.js:41:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

Node is installed in `/opt/nodejs/node-v0.10.0-linux-x64`. The `NODE_PATH` environment variable points to that path:

```
$ echo $NODE_PATH 
/opt/nodejs/node-v0.10.0-linux-x64
```

Even `yo init`fails with the same error.

Any suggestions what going wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was an error in Bower and got already fixed. You can manually update your bower installation or wait for the updated generators. [This is the commit](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/commit/c8188b4cb3c63db6298394328dfffda4dada247f) that fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes, after updating the npm repository via `npm -g update` it works fine again. Thanks.

Comment: hmm.  don't do npm -g update unless you have to. that is updating everything and is taking forever.  and it still did not fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I was able to make this all go away when I ran it with node 0.8.16. Using 0.10.0 caused it to bork.

Comment: Had the same issue just now.

Comment: Yap, node 0.10 isn't officially supported yet and there are many plugins and libraries that break.