# Grunt fail build "Arguments to path.join must be strings" error

Tags: node.js, yeoman, gruntjs

Updated to Node 0.10.0, now while Grunt server still works, Grunt (build) and Grunt Test return "Arguments to path.join must be strings" error on Running "useminPrepare:html" (useminPrepare) task, effectively failing to build.

Set up:
Node: 0.10.0
Yeoman: 1.0.0-beta.3 
Grunt: grunt-cli v0.1.6, grunt v0.4.0rc7

I know there's some fix been made, but tried all suggested solutions (npm cache clear, Grunt reinstall, etc.) with no success.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has been answered before here: [Yeoman yo webapp fails with TypeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357274/yeoman-yo-webapp-fails-with-typeerror)

To quote myself:

> This was an error in Bower and got already fixed. You can manually
>   update your bower installation or wait for the updated generators.
>   [This is the
>   commit](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/commit/c8188b4cb3c63db6298394328dfffda4dada247f)
>   that fixed the issue.

Comment: Did you `npm install` afterwards?

Comment: Yes, done that.
As I said in my original post, done everything by the book (aka read other posts and looked around for this ticket) but without success.

I'm building a angularJs app, using Yeoman, and since updating to NodeJS - (supposed) fix or not, it just does not build anymore.

Comment: Could you try to upgrade grunt to the latest revision in master? `npm install git://github.com/gruntjs/grunt.git`. I just saw that a similar incompatibility was fixed there two days ago.

Comment: Tried that as well, still broken... will try a reset and clean install (once more) / it's driving me nuts this thing.

Comment: Fixed! I was updating Grunt global but the app was somehow using a local instance, npm grunt install in the app dir solved the issue. thanks.

Comment: I'm still getting this error after following all the advice here. Any ideas?